# How to get XCode to recognise .C and .H files as C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, filesystems, case-sensitive

Currently XCode identifies .C and .H files in my project as C files and headers when selecting a syntax highlighting mode. The files are on a case sensitive file system. I would like them to be identified as C++ files and headers, which happens then I name them .cpp and .hpp.

Please note that this is a large project where I have control over a very small section, so renaming them to .cpp is not possible.

Comment: I think you have an option call `Compile Sources As` in your project setting, set it to `C++` or `Objective-C++` instead of according to file type.

Comment: I have set that option, however they are still identified as `C` by the syntax highlighter.